# Mysql: Multiple column primary key with null values

Tags: mysql, sql, nullable, composite-primary-key

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE items(
   id int,
   ...
)

CREATE TABLE types(
   id char(1),
   ...
)


CREATE TABLE prices(
   item int,
   type char(1) NULL, --can not be null because it is in PK!
   price decimal,
   PRIMARY KEY (item, version),
   FOREIGN KEY (item) REFERENCES items(id),
   FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES types(id)
)
```

Not all items have different price for type:

```
INSERT INTO prices (item, type, price)
VALUES (1,'A',10.0),
VALUES (1,'B',20.0),
VALUES (1,'C',20.0),
VALUES (2,NULL,50.0),
VALUES (3,'A',10.0),
VALUES (3,'B',20.0),
VALUES (4,NULL,70.0);
```

As you can se some items (2,4) have just one price.
This way I can set the foreign key between prices and types but I can not add type in the price's primary key because it is nullable... how to solve this problem? I need both foreign key and primary key to type field, but this can be optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a "surrogate" primary key on the prices table based on a identidy so you dont have to worry about mainting the pk column. You can then create a unique index across your item and type columns.

the id column which is your pk then just exists so mqsql can keep the rows organised on the file system.

Comment: I can add an unique key with null columns! I did not know that. Thanks